# :libs - c:\...\Blocks-Editor\app\js\dependencies\google-blockly\core\blocks.js is not a relative path

Tags: clojurescript, figwheel

Sorry, it must be something really stupid but I can't figure out what.

In the REPL, `(start-figwheel!)` outputs:

```
Figwheel: Starting server at http://0.0.0.0:3449
Figwheel: Watching build - dev
Compiling "app/js/compiled/app.js" from ["src" "dev/cljs/"]...
Failed to compile "app/js/compiled/app.js" in 0.907 seconds.
----  Exception    ----

c:\...\Blocks-Editor\app\js\dependencies\google-blockly\core\blocks.js is not a relative path

----  Exception Stack Trace  ----

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: c:\Users\u15194\Desktop\Blocks-Editor\app\js\dependencies\google-blockly\core\blocks.js is not a relative path
at clojure.java.io$as_relative_path.invokeStatic (io.clj:414)
clojure.java.io$file.invokeStatic (io.clj:426)
clojure.java.io$file.invoke (io.clj:418)
cljs.closure$write_javascript.invokeStatic (closure.clj:1636)
cljs.closure$write_javascript.invoke (closure.clj:1629)
cljs.closure$source_on_disk.invokeStatic (closure.clj:1675)
cljs.closure$source_on_disk.invoke (closure.clj:1670)
cljs.closure$output_unoptimized$fn__13822.invoke (closure.clj:1713)
clojure.core$map$fn__4785.invoke (core.clj:2646)
clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval (LazySeq.java:40)
clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq (LazySeq.java:49)
clojure.lang.RT.seq (RT.java:521)
clojure.core$seq__4357.invokeStatic (core.clj:137)
clojure.core$filter$fn__4812.invoke (core.clj:2700)
clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval (LazySeq.java:40)
clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq (LazySeq.java:49)
clojure.lang.RT.seq (RT.java:521)
clojure.core$seq__4357.invokeStatic (core.clj:137)
clojure.core$map$fn__4785.invoke (core.clj:2637)
clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval (LazySeq.java:40)
clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq (LazySeq.java:49)
clojure.lang.Cons.next (Cons.java:39)
clojure.lang.RT.next (RT.java:688)
clojure.core$next__4341.invokeStatic (core.clj:64)
clojure.core$str$fn__4419.invoke (core.clj:546)
clojure.core$str.invokeStatic (core.clj:544)
clojure.core$str.doInvoke (core.clj:533)
clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:139)
clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:646)
clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:641)
cljs.closure$deps_file.invokeStatic (closure.clj:1408)
cljs.closure$deps_file.invoke (closure.clj:1405)
cljs.closure$output_deps_file.invokeStatic (closure.clj:1428)
cljs.closure$output_deps_file.invoke (closure.clj:1427)
cljs.closure$output_unoptimized.invokeStatic (closure.clj:1721)
cljs.closure$output_unoptimized.doInvoke (closure.clj:1704)
clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:139)
clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:648)
clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:641)
cljs.closure$build.invokeStatic (closure.clj:2165)
cljs.closure$build.invoke (closure.clj:2055)
cljs.build.api$build.invokeStatic (api.clj:206)
cljs.build.api$build.invoke (api.clj:193)
figwheel_sidecar.components.cljs_autobuild$cljs_build.invokeStatic (cljs_autobuild.clj:28)
figwheel_sidecar.components.cljs_autobuild$cljs_build.invoke (cljs_autobuild.clj:27)
figwheel_sidecar.build_middleware.injection$hook$fn__24627.invoke (injection.clj:197)
figwheel_sidecar.components.cljs_autobuild$notify_command_hook$fn__25008.invoke (cljs_autobuild.clj:68)
figwheel_sidecar.components.cljs_autobuild$figwheel_start_and_end_messages$fn__25000.invoke (cljs_autobuild.clj:48)
figwheel_sidecar.components.cljs_autobuild$catch_print_hook$fn__25040.invoke (cljs_autobuild.clj:185)
figwheel_sidecar.components.cljs_autobuild$open_urls_hook$fn__25032.invoke (cljs_autobuild.clj:141)
figwheel_sidecar.build_middleware.stamp_and_clean$hook$fn__24985.invoke (stamp_and_clean.clj:66)
figwheel_sidecar.components.cljs_autobuild$color_output$fn__25012.invoke (cljs_autobuild.clj:79)
figwheel_sidecar.components.cljs_autobuild.CLJSAutobuild.start (cljs_autobuild.clj:255)
com.stuartsierra.component$eval23404$fn__23405$G__23394__23407.invoke (component.cljc:5)
com.stuartsierra.component$eval23404$fn__23405$G__23393__23410.invoke (component.cljc:5)
clojure.lang.Var.invoke (Var.java:379)
clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:154)
clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:700)
clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:648)
clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:641)
com.stuartsierra.component$try_action.invokeStatic (component.cljc:117)
com.stuartsierra.component$try_action.invoke (component.cljc:116)
com.stuartsierra.component$update_system$fn__23463.invoke (component.cljc:139)
clojure.lang.ArraySeq.reduce (ArraySeq.java:114)
clojure.core$reduce.invokeStatic (core.clj:6544)
clojure.core$reduce.invoke (core.clj:6527)
com.stuartsierra.component$update_system.invokeStatic (component.cljc:135)
com.stuartsierra.component$update_system.doInvoke (component.cljc:129)
clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:445)
com.stuartsierra.component$start_system.invokeStatic (component.cljc:163)
com.stuartsierra.component$start_system.invoke (component.cljc:155)
com.stuartsierra.component$start_system.invokeStatic (component.cljc:161)
com.stuartsierra.component$start_system.invoke (component.cljc:155)
com.stuartsierra.component.SystemMap.start (component.cljc:178)
com.stuartsierra.component$eval23404$fn__23405$G__23394__23407.invoke (component.cljc:5)
com.stuartsierra.component$eval23404$fn__23405$G__23393__23410.invoke (component.cljc:5)
clojure.lang.Atom.swap (Atom.java:37)
clojure.core$swap_BANG_.invokeStatic (core.clj:2260)
clojure.core$swap_BANG_.invoke (core.clj:2253)
figwheel_sidecar.system.FigwheelSystem.start (system.clj:118)
com.stuartsierra.component$eval23404$fn__23405$G__23394__23407.invoke (component.cljc:5)
com.stuartsierra.component$eval23404$fn__23405$G__23393__23410.invoke (component.cljc:5)
clojure.lang.Var.invoke (Var.java:379)
clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:154)
clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:700)
clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:648)
clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:641)
com.stuartsierra.component$try_action.invokeStatic (component.cljc:117)
com.stuartsierra.component$try_action.invoke (component.cljc:116)
com.stuartsierra.component$update_system$fn__23463.invoke (component.cljc:139)
clojure.lang.ArraySeq.reduce (ArraySeq.java:109)
clojure.core$reduce.invokeStatic (core.clj:6544)
clojure.core$reduce.invoke (core.clj:6527)
com.stuartsierra.component$update_system.invokeStatic (component.cljc:135)
com.stuartsierra.component$update_system.doInvoke (component.cljc:129)
clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:445)
com.stuartsierra.component$start_system.invokeStatic (component.cljc:163)
com.stuartsierra.component$start_system.invoke (component.cljc:155)
com.stuartsierra.component$start_system.invokeStatic (component.cljc:161)
com.stuartsierra.component$start_system.invoke (component.cljc:155)
com.stuartsierra.component.SystemMap.start (component.cljc:178)
figwheel_sidecar.system$start_figwheel_system$fn__25248.invoke (system.clj:658)
figwheel_sidecar.system$dispatch_system_component_errors.invokeStatic (system.clj:644)
figwheel_sidecar.system$dispatch_system_component_errors.invoke (system.clj:642)
figwheel_sidecar.system$start_figwheel_system.invokeStatic (system.clj:658)
figwheel_sidecar.system$start_figwheel_system.invoke (system.clj:656)
figwheel_sidecar.system$start_figwheel_BANG__STAR_.invokeStatic (system.clj:693)
figwheel_sidecar.system$start_figwheel_BANG__STAR_.invoke (system.clj:679)
clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:156)
clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo (AFn.java:144)
clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:646)
clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:641)
figwheel_sidecar.system$start_figwheel_BANG_.invokeStatic (system.clj:737)
figwheel_sidecar.system$start_figwheel_BANG_.doInvoke (system.clj:695)
clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:397)
clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:152)
clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:132)
clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:646)
clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:641)
figwheel_sidecar.repl_api$start_figwheel_BANG_$fn__25265.invoke (repl_api.clj:28)
clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:154)
clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo (AFn.java:144)
clojure.lang.Var.alterRoot (Var.java:303)
clojure.core$alter_var_root.invokeStatic (core.clj:5299)
clojure.core$alter_var_root.doInvoke (core.clj:5294)
clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:425)
figwheel_sidecar.repl_api$start_figwheel_BANG_.invokeStatic (repl_api.clj:28)
figwheel_sidecar.repl_api$start_figwheel_BANG_.doInvoke (repl_api.clj:25)
clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:397)
user$start.invokeStatic (user.clj:4)
user$start.invoke (user.clj:4)
user$eval85181.invokeStatic (form-init157753958820776154.clj:2248)
user$eval85181.invoke (form-init157753958820776154.clj:2248)
clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6927)
clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6890)
clojure.core$eval.invokeStatic (core.clj:3105)
clojure.core$eval.invoke (core.clj:3101)
clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__7408$fn__7411.invoke (main.clj:240)
clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__7408.invoke (main.clj:240)
clojure.main$repl$fn__7417.invoke (main.clj:258)
clojure.main$repl.invokeStatic (main.clj:258)
clojure.main$repl.doInvoke (main.clj:174)
clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:646)
clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:641)
refactor_nrepl.ns.slam.hound.regrow$wrap_clojure_repl$fn__43227.doInvoke (regrow.clj:18)
clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:1523)
clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate$fn__22540.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:87)
clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:152)
clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo (AFn.java:144)
clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:646)
clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.invokeStatic (core.clj:1881)
clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.doInvoke (core.clj:1881)
clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:425)
clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate.invokeStatic (interruptible_eval.clj:85)
clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:55)
clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$interruptible_eval$fn__22585$fn__22588.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:222)
clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$run_next$fn__22580.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:190)
clojure.lang.AFn.run (AFn.java:22)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (:-1)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (:-1)
java.lang.Thread.run (:-1)
```

I'm using [Google Blockly Library](https://github.com/google/blockly), which uses GCL

**What's wrong?**

Here's the project file tree:

```
app/
  js/
    dependencies/google-blockly/
    compiled/out/
dev/
src/ --> cljs
project.clj
```

google-blockly:

```
+---accessible
|   +---libs
|   \---media
+---appengine
+---blocks
+---core
+---demos
|   +---accessible
|   +---blockfactory
|   |   \---workspacefactory
|   +---blockfactory_old
|   +---code
|   |   \---msg
|   +---custom-dialogs
|   +---fixed
|   +---generator
|   +---graph
|   +---headless
|   +---interpreter
|   +---maxBlocks
|   +---mirror
|   +---plane
|   |   +---generated
|   |   +---soy
|   |   \---xlf
|   +---resizable
|   +---rtl
|   +---storage
|   \---toolbox
+---generators
|   +---dart
|   +---javascript
|   +---lua
|   +---php
|   \---python
+---i18n
+---media
+---msg
|   +---js
|   \---json
\---tests
    +---blocks
    +---generators
    +---jsunit
    \---workspace_svg
```

project.clj

```
(defproject blocks-editor "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "An editor for visual blocks programming built with ClojureScript + Electron" 
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.9.473" :exclusions [org.apache.ant/ant]]
                 [re-frame "0.9.2"]]

  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.1.5"]
            [lein-externs "0.1.6"]
            [lein-shell "0.5.0"]
            [lein-figwheel "0.5.9" :exclusions [org.clojure/core.cache]]]

  :profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[figwheel "0.5.9"]
                                  [figwheel-sidecar "0.5.9"]
                                  [com.cemerick/piggieback "0.2.1"]
                                  [binaryage/devtools "0.9.2"]]

                   :source-paths ["src" "dev"]}}

  :repl-options {:nrepl-middleware [cemerick.piggieback/wrap-cljs-repl]}

  :hooks [leiningen.cljsbuild] 
  :cljsbuild {:builds
              {:release {:source-paths ["src"]
                         :compiler {:output-to "app/js/compiled/app.js"
                                    :libs ["app/js/dependencies/google-blockly"]
                                    :main blocks-editor.init
                                    :optimizations :advanced}}

               :dev {:source-paths ["src" "dev/cljs/"]
                     :figwheel true
                     :compiler {:output-to "app/js/compiled/app.js"
                                :output-dir "app/js/compiled/out"
                                :main user.cljs
                                :libs ["app/js/dependencies/google-blockly"]

                                :asset-path "js/compiled/out"
                                :source-map-timestamp true
                                :preloads [devtools.preload]
                                :optimizations :none}}}}

  :clean-targets ^{:protect false} ["app/js/compiled"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly why you're getting that error, but it looks to me like figwheel or lein-cljsbuild is interpreting the relative path you've provided to blockly wrong, and is attempting to interpret it as an absolute one.  This kind of problem is often very tricky to resolve, but I have a couple of suggestions:

1. Try running in a different environment; if you're using `cmd`, try [git bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads), or (even better) [Bash for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/commandline/wsl/install_guide). You may well find that this resolves path issues, but obviously it's no good if you like your current environment (I would recommend Bash for Windows for everything clojure, mind).
2. Try packaging google-blockly in a jar in [cljsjs](https://github.com/cljsjs/packages#documentation); this is a bit of a pain, but on the flipside you'll be helping everyone else out too! Then you can just add it as a leiningen dependency like normal. Doing this for a google library should be easier than for most, as the difficulty normally comes from creating externs for things that don't work with google's closure compiler.
3. Check your line endings and file encodings are correct, it's an outside chance but in my experience sometimes this can cause path-related issues.
4. Check your clojurescript version, there might be an [outstanding issue](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/issues/516) that's affecting you...

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you sooo much!!! I thought nobody would answer. This project is very important to me. I chose ClojureScript as one the languages for my work of course conclusion, arguing that it would contribute to the project. If I don't solve this bug quickly, I'll have to drop Clojure :( . I'm going to try out your suggestions. Thanks again!

Comment: Good luck, and don't give up on Clojure!

Comment: I'm using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. Now I'm getting a different error: `sun.nio.fs.UnixException: Bad file descriptor
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixNativeDispatcher.read(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService$Poller.run(LinuxWatchService.java:318)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`. Any suggestions on this one?

Comment: Unfortunately for now you need to use later versions of the Windows Subsystem for Linux that are available through the Windows Insider Programme, sorry I forgot about this because I assumed it had made it into the regular Windows update cycle by now. If you turn that on in your Windows settings then you'll have a much better time running the JVM under bash. See [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1435) for more details.

Comment: I've been running it for so long I'd forgotten. I realise it may seem like one problem after another (and I suppose that's what it is) but I can assure you it does work just fine - I've been running figwheel in bash on Windows every day for the best part of a year

Comment: Oh, I see. Does installing the Insider version worth it? How much overhead?

Comment: I think it's worth it for bash. You'll get Windows whining at you to install updates more often, but that's about it. But it'll take a while to install.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141305/discussion-between-tiago-dalloca-and-conan).